# Usage of "sich zu etwas melden" and "sich für etwas melden" in the sense of "volunteering"?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, preposition

In standard dictionaries, such as Duden and Langenscheidt, the preposition *zu* is mentioned in *sich zu etwas melden*, which means *to volunteer for something*; e.g. "Wer meldet sich freiwillig zum Geschirrspülen?" (quoted from Langenscheidt Großwörterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache).

Meanwhile, I read the following example sentence in Farrell's Dictionary of German Synonyms:

> Er meldete sich freiwillig für den Dienst im Ausland, doch ließ seine Begeisterung rasch nach.

In this example, the preposition *für* is used instead of *zu*. I am wondering whether this usage is really correct and whether there is any difference in meaning in this particular case of *sich melden*, that arises from the different choice between *zu* and *für*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, there is a difference between the use of *sich melden zu* and *sich melden für* (even though I couldn’t find references).
I would use *sich melden zu* to signal that I am here and ready to work. Whereas with *sich melden für* I would show the willingness to do the job in general/later.

Example with *zu*:

> A: “Ich melde mich zum Putzen”
>
> B: “Gut, dann mach bitte als erstes xy”.

Example with *für*:

> A: “Ich melde mich für das Putzen”
>
> B: “Gut, wir treffen uns 14 Uhr und
> verteilen dann die Aufgaben.”

Comment: I'd add, that at least to me, sich "zu" etwas melden also has a tad of a military ring to it, while "für" is more neutral.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct as well, and there is no difference in meaning.

There is only a small difference in usage: "sich melden zu" can only be used with an activity, say,

> *sich zum Dienst melden*
>
> *sich zum Geschirrspülen melden*

whereas "sich melden für" can be used with an activity, but also with a place or time (where/when the activity takes place) or an object (that is used for the activity), say

> *sich für den Dienst melden*
>
> *sich fürs Geschirrspülen melden*
>
> *sich für die Küche melden*
>
> *sich für Samstag melden*
>
> *sich fürs Geschirr melden*

Comment: thanks, in your stance, the following two ,,Wer meldet sich zum Geschirrspülen / Wer meldet sich fürs Geschirrspülen''  are equally acceptable, right?

Comment: @Lynnyo yes, both are fine.